# Empty text node added before paragraph. Why?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

`body`-HTML:

```html
<body>
    <div id="header-image">
        <img id="logo" src="/res/img/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="menu-container">
                <ul>
            <li class="login"><a href="/login.php">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
            </div>
    <div id="content">﻿<p class="info-box error">Der Benutzer <span class="username">a</span> existert nicht.</p><form action="" method="post">
    <input class="text" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Benutzername" /><br />
    <input class="text" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Passwort" /><br />
    <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button><button type="submit" name="register">Beitreten</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

I know the white-space formatting is not really nice for the human eye but that should not afflict the browsers rendering (its generated by some dirty PHP, that is why).

So the problem is that Chromes DevTools shows the following empty text:
[image: DevTools with empty text]

And also does not collapse the margins of my `.info-box.error` with that of the `#menu-container` plus **it renders the space of one empty line between the beginning of `#content` and `.info-box.error`.** Assuming I have `margin: 10px;` on `#menu-container, .info-box`, this causes, in summary, more than 30 pixels of space where only should be `10px` (because of collapsing margins).

I do not want this empty line. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: I copy pasted your code to jsfiddle and I see a [dirty character there](http://jsfiddle.net/Ah7jc/)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Is this an answer or a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text node is not empty but consists of the (invisible) U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE character. It is treated as a data character, not whitespace, except when it appears at the very start of a document, where it acts as Byte Order Mark (BOM).

So it should be removed, probably by changing the encoding of some PHP file from “UTF-8 with BOM” to “UTF-8 without BOM”, as @Foxhoundn suggests.

It is one of the longstanding bugs in PHP software that it does not remove the BOM when concatenating files. A BOM at the start of an HTML document is fine, even recommendable, but not at the start of a PHP file if that file ever gets appended or inserted, by PHP software, to another file.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if you have the document encoding in "without BOM" formatting in your editor. Looks like an encoding issue character to me.

Answer (score 0):

try to format your HTML code. It has some invalid character because of encoder.